# ScreenResolutionCompatibilityMode not working in version 14 on Windows 11

Tags: front-end, scaling, magnification, version-14

I'm facing a problem with the relative scale of fonts and controls in Mathematica. In version 14, the `ScreenResolutionCompatibilityMode` (in CTRL+SHIFT+O settings) option stopped affecting anything. In 13.3.1, setting it to True made most fonts in Mathematica the same size as in other applications and the operating system.

I have a 1920x1080 screen with a 120 Hz refresh rate, Windows 11, and Mathematica 14.0.

[image: Version 13.3.1]
*Version 13.3.1*

[image: Version 14.0.0]
*Version 14.0.0*

Another good way to show is that the scales of fonts and elements don't match each other in the autocompletion popup:

[image: autocompletion]

How do I customize the scale of fonts and controls?

Comment: I have this problem too. I've scaled everything to 75% because I don't like how everything got really big. But now the code in the documentation is tiny.

Comment: @flinty yes, you are right. I'm even more frustrated by the fact that different elements have different scales - like the autocompletion window, for example

Comment: You might try to set DPI settings or compatibility mode in Windows, this feature arrived in Windows 7 and can help to deal with this issue. The settings can be applied individually to any app

Comment: @Kirill Belov: What is so frustrating about autocompletion font being smaller than usual code??? I have version 13 and autocompletion font is smaller too, but I think it is a feature not a bug because more entries can be visible in autocompletion window and I like it that way.

Comment: @azerbajdzan this applies not only to the auto add-on window, but to all controls and fonts in general. They just became different everywhere. Window title, size in cells of different types, popups, size of charts, presentations. In 13.3.1 fonts could be brought to more or less the same standard with an option from the question, but now it has no effect on anything

Comment: What about setting "Global magnification" to 75% in the Preference setting?

Comment: @TaikiBessho yes, I currently have, but I still have a feeling of imperfection. I want the default settings to be the most well adjusted. Here I can see that almost any Windows user who installs the new version will find that they will have to adjust to the right scale for them